# Workspace type interface in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

MFC provides the MDI and SDI interfaces as standard. I'd like to implement a "Workspace Document Interface" (as it's called by Stingray's Objective Toolkit) in MFC.

This is not quite pure MDI since only a single "workspace" document can be opened. But it's clearly not SDI since multiple documents and views can be open. In fact, most IDEs themselves are WDI and not MDI.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this? Is it as simple as just checking if the user has already opened a workspace filetype?

Comment: VS2013 MFC templates have the options SDI, MDI, Dialog or "Multiple top level documents". I think that last one sounds most like what you describe - I've used it for similar arrangements where my multiple documents are all in different tabs.

Comment: Hi Roger - that's kind of multiple SDIs that 'share' a single thread (e.g. WORD). It's not quite the workspace model.